# Error postgres at launch script in docker container

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, docker-compose, psql

I have a bash script to download and restore a postgres database (all correct here).

I have a docker-compose where I put `command= scrip_psql.sh`, and when I run `docker-compose up`, I have this error:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
> postgres-backup |   Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

But when I delete the part of `command= scrip_psql.sh` in docker-compose, I can launch the container, launch a bash console in it, and launch manually the script, it works.

I tried different configurations in the script and in the docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check on your `scrip_psql.sh` to see if there is some conflicting parameters that might need to change or are different from the normal running of the Docker compose without any specified file for the command in your docker compose file. Check whether the commands in the bash file matches your running cluster parameters for instance the port number.